# android dialog leaking window in android 4.0 but not in 2.3

Tags: android, dialog

i have an alert dialog with a continue button.
when click the button the dialog should dismiss and lunch a new Intent.
from some reason in Android 2.3 it works good but in Android 4.0 i get window leak...
this is my code:

```
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cls != null)
                {
                    dismiss();
                    Intent i = new Intent(activity,cls);
                    activity.startActivity(i);
                }
             }
        });
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a button inside the AlertDialog's view? If not, you can use AlertDialogue.Builder.setPositivebutton / negative / neutral to move out of the dialogue. Clicking these buttons automatically dismiss the dialogue.